# I'm an undergraduate seeking to recruit academics for a research project: where and how can I recruit?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

I am currently searching for participants to take part in my research exploring the work-life balance of academics who are fathers. However, so far recruitment has been unsuccessful.

Does anyone have suggestions of how or where I can advertise to recruit?

The approval from the ethics committee has been granted.

Comment: Perhaps start off with academics in your own department/university. Ask your supervisor if there is a mailing list they can forward your request to, for example.

Comment: Mailing list is a good suggestion. I'd also add "be as much upfront as possible" - people might be curious and willing to participate, but filling a google form without prior commitment is much different from agreeing to provide answers to questions one might be uncomfortable with. Also, do include a feedback form (just an optional text box asking for difficulties one had answering or possible improvements) - more often than not, the studies I've participated in seemed flawed and fairly biased by design.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to send emails to department heads (who usually have public email addresses) with a short abstract of what you want to study and asking if they will pass on a request for volunteers to appropriate faculty. Some will respond favorably, but many others will just delete the mail. You might get slightly better response if your advisor sends the mail on your behalf as a request from a faculty member is a bit harder to ignore.

However, make sure you have the appropriate sign-off from the local ethical committee before you complete your design, since you are dealing with human subjects. There will be privacy and other concerns.

The big problem, as I see it, is that you won't be able to conclude much from such a study as it will be very difficult to assure that you have a random sample of the population of study. You can get anecdotal evidence, but your sample will be self selected, which leads to the issue of likely bias that is hard to measure.

You might be able to examine extreme views from such a study. My (somewhat cloudy) crystal ball suggests that the extremely pleased and the extremely dissatisfied are more likely to submit to an interview than the "typical" faculty member.

Some things are very hard to study if you want any validity at all. And note, also, that for issues like this the population changes every day, since policies are in general flux. And don't neglect the fact that "general" satisfaction with work-life balance might be quite different in, say, philosophy and pharmacology.